# Criteria Builder Convert Lower

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have the following Predicate condition

```
  predicate = 
  cb.like(root.get(Product_.prodName),prod.getProductName());
```

How to use lower in the above starement, I have tried as

```
predicate = 
cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Product_.prodName), prod.getProdName());
```

However it gives me the following error

```
method lower(javax.persistence.criteria.Path<java.lang.String>,
java.lang.String) not found in interface 
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
```

What is the correct way to convert to lower?

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using? And you would like to search using ignore case or lower case?

Comment: @TheCodingFrog I am using EclipseLink 2.5.2

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't compile for a different reason: it's missing a parenthesis. The error you get on the actual code also seems to be caused by a misplaced parenthesis. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to

```
predicate = 
    criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(Product_.prodName)), 
                         wrapper.getProdName());
```